# Fixing cuts on the seat

Tags: seat

I don't know how these cuts happened (picture below), but on taking it to the official service station, the mechanic said he'd try fixing it with black insulation tape.
I didn't think insulation tape was a good idea. My brother suggests putting a seat cover over it. Are these the only ways to fix it? Anything that is easier and does not make it look bad?

[image]

Comment: I've never used it for this, specifically, but you'd be amazed what you can do with super glue. That'd be my first try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to cover up the seat or reupholster it then you might have some luck buying some leather patch repair kit like this.
[http://www.amazon.com/3M-08579-Leather-Vinyl-Repair/dp/B0058WXNOK/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1424309626&sr=8-4&keywords=leather+seat+patch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058WXNOK)

Answer (score 0):

Look for a Dr.Vinyl franchise in your area. We used to use them all the time when I worked at a GMC dealer. They were very good and could match most any color and grain pattern.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think Dr.Vinyl is available in India.